# Hybris - How to load our launch B2C ASM module

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have successfully loaded the Hybris (6.0) B2C Accelerator but when I log into the back office and attempt to launch the ASM module it just launches my local instance of the website instead of the ASM.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to :

- Install the "assistedservice*" extensions
- Install the ASM add-on into your accelerator store front extension
- Run "ant all" and update your system
- Access the store front with the argument "?asm=true"